# PHP - editing a string from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a database which presents as the following;

```
< channel\01273123456:d24gf3fm >
```

I need to export the number from this string, the first "< channel\" is always the same, but the end ID is always unique.

I currently have the following code, but cannot think, nor find what I need to export the number.

```
//connection
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die ("Unable to connect to Database"); 
echo "Connected\n";

//select DB

$selected = mysql_select_db("asterisk", $dbhandle)
or die("Could not select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo echo "channel:".$row{'channel'}."\n";

}
```

Hope someone could help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: This `echo echo "channel:".$row{'channel'}.` is incorrect, and you're missing an ending semi-colon on top of that.

Comment: Sorry, I do apologise, I copied the code and didn't select the end semi-colon. I've edited my OP.

Comment: this is invalid-> `"SELECT * FROM TABLE"`; use mysqli or pdo; `echo echo` is invalid. fix the simple issues first then see what happens.

Comment: You're using 2x echos, first mistake. Then the braces in `echo echo "channel:".$row{'channel'}."\n";` doesn't look right to me, but I could be wrong. Have you tried using brackets? I.e.: `echo "channel:".$row['channel']."\n";`

Comment: Plus, "IF"... the big **IF**, by any chance you're actually using `TABLE` as your table name, wrap it in backticks. It's a reserved word. (One never knows nowadays).

Comment: why are you using this symbole '\' in your database ? its something of escaping .

Answer (score 1):

Substr seems to be the function you are seeking for:

[substr](https://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php).

Try something like this (depends on if you need the whole last part of the string or only the part until the ':':

```
$yourString = substr($row['channel'], strpos($row['channel'], '\'));
```

Would give you the whole substring. If you do not need the part after the the ':' you need no split yourString again from 0 to position of ':'.

```
$yourString2 = substr($yourString, 0, strpos($subString, ':'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick and as requested by tadman and it's a function :)

```
public function cleanMyString($string)
{
    // remove channel garbage
    // 01273123456:d24gf3fm >
    $string = substr($string, 10, (strlen($string) - 10));

    // remove space and >
    // 01273123456:d24gf3fm
    $string = substr($string, 0, -2);

    // split on colon
    // $colons[0] = 01273123456
    // $colons[1] = d24gf3fm
    $colons = explode(':', $string);

    // first item in array is the channel
    echo 'Channel: '.$colons[0].'<br><br>';
    // second item is ID
    echo 'ID: '.$colons[1];
}

// string, yay!
cleanMyString('< channel\\01273123456:d24gf3fm >');
```

Comment: This would make a lot more sense wrapped up in a function. Inline code like this creates a big mess.

Comment: Nice, looks way better, though really the `echo` shouldn't be inside the function. Instead: `echo cleanMyString(...)`. A function like that shouldn't presume how the result will be used.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried these?

```
SELECT Right (LEFT(`your_column`, 21),11) as numbers 
from asterisk
```

or this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`your_column`,'\', -1),':', 1) as numbers 
from asterisk
```